# Not showing Checkbox in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Hi I'm trying to run a checkbox field in mvc base on video tutorial that i've watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KeoOPWshmw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=38, I follow it carefully. but there is a problem the checkbox is not showing in my browser.

it shows only a text 12345 and a button submit.

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcCheckBox.Models.City>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

---

City.cshtml

```
@model MvcCheckBox.Models.City

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
```

Comment: Is `City.cshtml` located in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/`? Also try `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)`

Comment: no it is located in /Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ .
i also try @Html.EditorFor(m => m) but nothing changed..
thanks for the reply

Comment: So is the `Index.cshtml` view in `/Views/Home/`?

Comment: yes it is.
do you think there is a problem on installing my mvc4? 
did you try to run this in your mvc?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Have you put a breakpoint in `City.cshtml` to check it it's being hit?

Comment: yeah, it did not read the city.cshtml ..  it think i found my fault the folder "EditorTemplate" it should be "EditorTemplates"  its working now. why is that it did not consider EditorTemplate?

Comment: That's the naming convention used by MVC for searching locations

Comment: ok :) thanks for helping. appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From watching the video, you probably missed this step out:

> Right click on "EditorTemplates" folder - Add - View. In the "Add
>   View" dialog box, set View Name = City View Engine = Razor and click
>   "Add".

Then copy and paste your code into it:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "City";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
```